# InvalidCastException when removing item from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a prism View with a ListView, a Button and a ObservableCollection. When i remove an item from that collection i get a InvalidCastException on the Remove() call. What am i doing wrong?

View.xaml:

```
<ListView Name="lvSomeEntities" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeEntityList}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LvSelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lvSomeEntities, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>

<Button Name="button" Content="Delete SomeEntity" Command="{Binding DeleteSomeEntityCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lvSomeEntities, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
public DelegateCommand<SomeEntity> DeleteSomeEntityCommand { get; private set; }

private ObservableCollection<SomeEntity> _someEntityList = new ObservableCollection<SomeEntity>();
public ObservableCollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntityList
{
    get { return _someEntityList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _someEntityList, value); }
}

public ViewModel()
{
    DeleteSomeEntityCommand = new DelegateCommand<SomeEntity>(DeleteSomeEntity, DeleteSomeEntityEnabled);
}

private void DeleteSomeEntity(SomeEntity someEntity)
{
    SomeEntityList.Remove(someEntity);//here i get the InvalidCastException
}

private bool DeleteSomeEntityEnabled(SomeEntity someEntity)
{
    return someEntity != null;
}
```

SomeEntity.cs:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public SomeEntity(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id + " " + Name;
    }
}
```

Exception Message:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs' to type 'SomeEntity'.'

The funny part is, when the exception is thrown and i check the content of the ObservableCollection in the debugger, the item is actually removed.

Comment: Probably the execption occurs within a CollectionChanged event handler attached to this ObservableCollection. The full stack trace of the exception should tell you more.

Comment: Remove the whole `<i:Interaction.Triggers>... </i:Interaction.Triggers>` block. It causes the exception - after the item already has been removed by pressing the button. It seems to make no sense. Do you really want to remove an item anytime the selection in the list changes?

Comment: I use the LvSelectionChangedCommand to update the DeleteSomeEntityEnabled so the delete button gets enabled only when an item in te listview is selected . I am not removing the item when the selection changes...

Comment: It would be easier to bind `lvSomeEntities`'s `SelectedItem` to a property on the view model (instead of having a command perform essentially the setter's job).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I removed now the `<i:Interaction.Triggers>... </i:Interaction.Triggers>` and binded the SelectedItem of my ListView to a property as suggested from @Haukinger. To replace the LvSelectionChanged i now call this method from the setter of the property. That works but does not explain the exception i had.

Comment: It might be a misconfiguration of Prism's `InvokeCommandAction` - obviously it ignores the `CommandParameter` and passes the `EventArgs` instead. You could try other implementations, like the one from `Xaml.Behaviors`.